# Intersection of Countably Infinite Sequence of Sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose $\{\Omega_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence of sets, where $\Omega_k$ is countably infinite and $\Omega_{k+1}\subset\Omega_k$ for all $k$. Is it possible to show that $\cap _{k=1}^{\infty} \Omega_k$ is countably infinite?

Comment: Ωk = { k+1,k+2,......}, so each Ωk contains all the integers after k+1 and so is countably infinite. However  ∩ Ωk = { }

Answer (score 5):

No; in fact it is not even possible to show it is nonempty in general! For an example, consider $\Omega_k=(0,1/k) \cap \mathbb{Q}$.

By the way, this is a special case of an important fact from measure theory: the measure of a descending countable intersection is equal to the limit of the measures of the sets *if* one of the sets has finite measure. Otherwise it might be smaller than this limit. Your case is the situation with the counting measure; a similar situation occurs with $\Omega_k = [k,\infty)$ under the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: This was exactly the example I wanted. Beat me to it. +1